# traverse directory structure in python recursively without os.walk

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, recursion

I am trying to write a python2 function that will recursively traverse through the whole directory structure of a given directory, and print out the results.

All without using os.walk

This is what I have got so far:

```
test_path = "/home/user/Developer/test"

def scanning(sPath):
    output = os.path.join(sPath, 'output')
    if os.path.exists(output):
        with open(output) as file1:
            for line in file1:
                if line.startswith('Final value:'):
                    print line
    else:
        for name in os.listdir(sPath):
            path = os.path.join(sPath, name)
            if os.path.isdir(path):
                print "'", name, "'"
                print_directory_contents(path)

scanning(test_path)
```

This is what I currently get, the script doesn't enter the new folder:

```
' test2'
'new_folder'
```

The issue is that it does not go further down than one directory.  I would also like to able to indicate visually what is a directory, and what is a file

Comment: Unfortunately,  `os.walk` is still the most feasible folder listing mechanism even under python 3.

Comment: I would much rather use it!  However it has been requested that I don't use os.walk :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a recursive function,

```
def lastline(fil):
    with open(fil) as f:
        for li in f.readlines():
            if li.startswith("Final Value:"):
                print(li)

## If it still doesnt work try putting 'dirs=[]' here
def lookforfiles(basepath):
    contents = os.listdir(basepath)

    dirs = []
    i = 0

    while i <= len(contents):
        i += 1

        for n in contents:
            f = os.path.join(basepath, n)

            if os.path.isfile(f):
                lastline(f)
                print("\n\nfile %s" % n)
            elif os.path.isdir(f):
                print("Adding dir")
                if f in dirs:
                    pass
                else:
                    dirs.append(f)

    else:   
        for x in dirs:
            print("dir %s" % x)
            lookforfiles(x)
```

sorry if this doesn't fit your example precisely but I had a hard time understanding what you were trying to do.

Comment: the f in your lookforfiles function appears as an unresolved reference, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I caught that myself. My brain added code that my hands didn't get to. Just edited it lol.

Comment: haha No worries, happens to everyone!  Although I am getting an error with your code:

     TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found

in the lookforfiles function on line: contents = os.listdir(basepath)

Comment: be sure the directory is correct and give os.listdir a try in your console with any directory. just so you can see the output.

Comment: Alright this works on my end just beware that when reading files sometimes it wont be able to tell the type and will throw and exception if it cant read the text.

Comment: Hi Dantastic, this works really well, but it seems to be printing everything twice, I was working through it there but I could not find the answer :(  Any thoughts?

Comment: I added an if...else...statement to the end so it wouldn't look through directories twice. I am glad the answer above works. I was concerned when looking at it that it would not back out of a directory once it hit one. Good luck.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
import os

test_path = "YOUR_DIRECTORY"

def print_directory_contents(dir_path):
    for child in os.listdir(dir_path):
        path = os.path.join(dir_path, child)
        if os.path.isdir(path):
            print("FOLDER: " + "\t" + path)
            print_directory_contents(path)

        else:
            print("FILE: " + "\t" + path)

print_directory_contents(test_path)
```

I worked on windows, verify if still working on unix.
Adapted from:
http://codegists.com/snippet/python/print_directory_contentspy_skobnikoff_python

Comment: I can confirm I using linux :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this out with recursion 
it is much simple and less code

```
import os

def getFiles(path="/var/log", files=[]):
    if os.path.isfile(path):
        return files.append(path)
    for item in os.listdir(path):
        item = os.path.join(path, item)
        if os.path.isfile(item):
            files.append(item)
        else:
            files = getFiles(item, files)
    return files  



for f in getFiles("/home/afouda/test", []):
    print(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is a duplicate of [Print out the whole directory tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17576366/print-out-the-whole-directory-tree).

TL;TR: Use `os.listdir`.