# sort excel files using column value python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sorting

I have n excel files and I need to sort them according to a column's value. In fact, I need to organize my excel files placed under a specific folder in creating subfolders and each subfolder contains excel files with the same `DEPTNAME`, knowing that `DEPTNAME` is a column name and each excel file has m sheets but all the sheets have the same `DEPTNAME`.

**Example**:
A folder with 4 excel files:

```
df1= pd.DataFrame({'Last Name':[‘Stark’, ‘Stark’, ‘ Stark’, ‘Stark’],
 'FirstName':['Arya', ,'Arya','Arya','Arya',],
 'DEPTNAME':['Sécu','Sécu','Sécu','Sécu']})
```

[image]

```
df2= pd.DataFrame({'Last Name':[‘Lannister’, ‘Lannister’, ‘ Lannister’, ‘Lannister’],
 'FirstName':['Cersei', ,'Cersei','Cersei','Cersei',],
 'DEPTNAME':['Auto','Auto','Auto','Auto']})
```

[image]

```
df3= pd.DataFrame({'Last Name':[‘Snow’, ‘Snow’, ‘ Snow’, ‘Snow’, ‘ Snow’, ‘Snow’],
         'FirstName':['Jon', 'Jon','Jon','Jon','Jon','Jon'],
         'DEPTNAME':['Aero','Aero','Aero','Aero','Aero','Aero']})
```

[image]

```
df4= pd.DataFrame({'Last Name':[‘Lannister’, ‘Lannister’, ‘ Lannister’, ‘Lannister’],
         'FirstName':['Tyrion', 'Tyrion','Tyrion','Tyrion',],
         'DEPTNAME':['Aero','Aero','Aero','Aero']})
```

[image]

Now I need to create automatically 3 folders: `Sécu`, `Aero` and `Auto`.

`Sécu` will contain one excel file

`Aero` will contain two excel files

`Auto` will contain one excel file

**is it doable** knowing that my **initial folder contains n excel files with multiple sheets**?

Comment: all the data files have the same columns but the length differs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is one way which combines all files in a folder and all sheets in each file and then groups on `DEPTNAME` and the filename +  sorts the files in the folder(Note: if same `DEPTNAME` are in 2 different excel fies, they are saves as 2 different files in the same folder <- as requested):

```
def myf(folder,files_to_be_created_in_folder):
    """ folder is the path to input files and files_to_be_created_in_folder
         is the path where the directories are to be created"""
    folder = folder
    list_of_files=os.listdir(folder)
    combined_sheets={i[:-5]:pd.concat(pd.read_excel(os.path.join(folder,i),sheet_name=None)
        .values(),sort=False)for i in list_of_files}
    combined_all_files=pd.concat(combined_sheets.values(),keys=combined_sheets.keys())
    d={i:g for i,g in combined_all_files.groupby(['DEPTNAME'
             ,combined_all_files.index.get_level_values(0)])}
    to_create_folder=files_to_be_created_in_folder
    for k,v in d.items():
        newpath=os.path.join(to_create_folder,k[0])
        if not os.path.exists(newpath):
            os.makedirs(newpath)
        v.to_excel(os.path.join(newpath,f"{k[1]}.xlsx"),index=False)
```

---

```
myf(r'C:\path_to_files\test_folder',r'C:\path_to_write\New folder') #replace paths carefully
```

---

For testing I have tried t print a folder tree based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45599996/9840637) solution which depicts a folder tree:

```
ptree(r'C:\path_to_files\test_folder')

test_folder/
|-- test_1.xlsx
|-- test_2.xlsx
|-- test_3.xlsx
|-- test_4.xlsx

ptree(r'C:\path_to_write\New folder') #this also has the test folder

New folder/
|-- Aero/
|   |-- test_3.xlsx
|   |-- test_4.xlsx
|-- Auto/
|   |-- test_2.xlsx
|-- Sécu/
|   |-- test_1.xlsx
|-- test_folder/
|   |-- test_1.xlsx
|   |-- test_2.xlsx
|   |-- test_3.xlsx
|   |-- test_4.xlsx
```

Comment: thank you, it worked like magic but can you please explain to me the utility of this line of code `myf(r'C:\path_to_files\test_folder',r'C:\path_to_write\New folder')` because my dataframes were already sorted is this directory `files_to_be_created_in_folder`

Comment: @A.khou that line is just to execute the function, since all the code is wrapped under the function `myf` , which takes 2 parameters, your input folder path and the output folder path, if you delete the output folders and just run myf with the params, you would see the code creating 3 folders in the output directory

Comment: if you want the new folders to be created in the same input folder, pass the same folder path as input and output in the function